# Carregar página com evento Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

preciso de uma ajuda. Tem um evento do jQuery que funciona do jeito que quero. Quando clico, ele executa a ação.

```
   $("#SEN").click(function(){
   $("#abre").show(); //ou fadeIn
   });
```

Meu intuito é que, em outra página, recupera dados de um cliente e, quando deixo `checked` no `radio` que executa a ação, não pega apenas pelo carregamento da página.

Resumo é carregar a página e executar evento do `radio` selecionado sem interação do usuário.

Já tentei assim e não vai:

```
 $("#SEN").bind('onload, change',function(){
 $("#abre").show();
 });
```

assim tbm:

```
 $('#SEN').on('onload, change',function() {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    $("#abre").show();
  } 
});
```

E com trigger e nada :(

```
 $('#SEN').on('onload, change',function() {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    $("#abre").show();
  } 
}).trigger("change");
```

Talvez esteja fazendo errado podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui assim:

```
 $('#SEN').on('onload, change',function() {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    $("#abre").show();
  } 
}).trigger("change");
```

Comment: também poderia usar `if ($('#elemento').is(':checked')) {   $("#abre").show();  }`

Comment: Sua explicação ficou incompreensível, eu só entendi o que você queria  pelo código que você tentou fazer.

Comment: vou explicar novamente. Tem um evento na pagina que funciona com click  perfeitamente. certo? Nessa mesma tela recupero dados dos clientes e queria que quando carregasse a pagina como já estaria selecionado os select radio etc, abrisse o evento no carregameto da pagina. Entendeu agora?

Answer (score 2):

Ficou um pouco confuso a sua explicação, mas seria quando o `radio` estiver `checked` executar uma ação?

pode ser feito desta forma:

```js
if ($("#mycheckbox").prop("checked")) {
  alert("Execute uma ação");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" checked/>
```

Comment: Seria no carregamento da página o evento já selecionado executar

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade? e só colocar para verificar se ele esta checado quando carregar a página.

Comment: funcionou assim 

$('#SEN').on('onload, change',function() {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    $("#abre").show();
  } 
}).trigger("change");

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema do seu código seja o evento que estais passando como parâmetro.

De acordo com a documentação da jquery, quando você usa o método "on", o evento não tem "on" no nome, por exemplo, se o evento javascript é "onload", você deve passar como parâmetro apenas "load".

https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Além disso, ao tratar o evento "change", provavelmente o "checked" é de um outro elemento que não será o "this" pois este é um elemento "select" e não um "checkbox", então você tem que pegar o checkbox pelo id ou de alguma outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Eu penso que você precisa de alguma coisa dessa maneira:

```
$('.checks')
    .on('load, change',function() {
       var i=0;
     $("input.checks:checked").each(function(){
         i++;
      });

       if ( i > 0) {
           $('#abre').show();
       } else {
           $('#abre').hide();
       }

}).trigger("change");
```

E o HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checks"> Elemento checado 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks"> Elemento checado 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks"> Elemento checado 3
<div id="abre" style="display:none">olá!</div>
```

Aqui o exemplo: **http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/5n7dyvx7/**